# JSP is not rendered in Spring boot

Tags: jsp, spring-boot

for hours now I am reading instructions how to render JSP pages in Spring Boot.
What I have done so far is to adapt pom.xm ( it includes the necessary packages for JSP and it will be deployed as a WAR file ), and application.properties.
But my login.jsp is not be shown. If I use my old login.html ( does not include any JSP ) in src\main\resources it is working.

I use STS Eclipse for my project.

My package structure:

[image]

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
<artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
<version>4.6.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class MatildaApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MatildaApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
    return new AuditorAwareImpl();
}
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.authorizeRequests()    .antMatchers("/","/js/**","/css/**","/img/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/registration/**","/h2_console/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.permitAll()
.and()
.logout()
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.clearAuthentication(true)
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
.permitAll()
.and()
.exceptionHandling()
.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@GetMapping("/")
public String root() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model) {
    return "login";
}

@GetMapping("/user")
public String userIndex() {
    return "user/index";
}

@GetMapping("/mitarbeiterverwaltung")
public String mitarbeiterverwaltung() {
    return "mitarbeiterverwaltung";
}    
}
```

Maybe someone knows what I am missing?

Comment: Have you created a controller? There should be a @Controller class which defined a get mapping on /login and returns the string "login"

Comment: Yes I have. So does my Controller look like:                        @Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String userIndex() {
        return "user/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/mitarbeiterverwaltung")
    public String mitarbeiterverwaltung() {
        return "mitarbeiterverwaltung";
    }    
}

Comment: Please paste the formatted code in the question. And when you say it is not being shown, what is it giving you? Also, how is your package structure defined?

Comment: I did as you requested

Comment: login seems to be mapped to / in the code you've pasted, is it a typo?

Comment: No, that is ok - as soon as you call any website and you are not already logged in you will be forwawrded to localhost:8080/login

Comment: But you still need to have the mapping defined for /login..

Comment: I am sorry, that was a typo, I understood you wrong. I changed it but it is still not working.

Comment: What do you mean "deployed as a war file"? Springboot is a self contained runtime.

Comment: What I read was that it has to be deployed as a war file, for later. I thought it would be better to describe what I have already done although this was a little bit useless, I agree.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post and added a screenshot. I hope it is that what you wanted.

Comment: @user3003944 Where is your main class ?

Comment: I added my Main class to my initial post.